# Getting UniformInterfaceException when trying to PUT into rest service

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, rest, put

I have been receiving this exception when I try to do a put request.

Here is the rest service

```
@Path("NearService")
public class NearService {
  private Feed feed = new Feed();

  @PUT
  @Path("/getLatestNearMe")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

  public GenericEntity<List<Post>> getLatestNearMe(User user){
      return new GenericEntity<List<Post>>(feed.getLatestNearMe(user)){};
  }
}
```

The Feed class utilizes hibernate and compares the coordinates of the user that is passed to other users and returns a List of posts within a certain radius.

Here is the client

```
List<Post> list = thisResource.path("getLatestNearMe").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(new GenericType<List<Post>>(){}, user);

for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getId());
}
```

Here is the error I keep receiving

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: PUT http://localhost:8080/NearService/rest/NearService/getPeopleNearMe returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:700)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$300(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:545)
at com.eviac.blog.restclient.NearClient.main(NearClient.java:35)
```

Here is the console output on the server

```
Jun 30, 2014 3:02:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path     [/NearService] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/hibernate/HibernateException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at com.near.service.NearService.<init>(NearService.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:245)
at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:233)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$PerRequest._getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:182)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$AbstractPerRequest.getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:144)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext.getResource(WebApplicationContext.java:239)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any input is very much appreatiated

Comment: The exception says that the server "returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error", which suggests that an exception is being thrown in the server (or something similar). Have you checked the server logs?